# Why we pass styles in array in component in Angular?

Tags: angular

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-course',
  templateUrl: './course.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course.component.css'],
  styles:[
  `


  `],
})
```

Why we pass styles in array in component in Angular unlike template ?

Comment: because you can add multiple css files in a component

Comment: StyleUrls is a array so you can add multiple styles to you component.
For more information, you should referer to the officiel documentation about component styles.  https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#styles-in-metadata) to read more on it and look at examples given. You can add multiple CSS styles to that `component` as an array.
For example,

```
@Component({
  selector: 'hero-app',
  template: `
    <h1>Tour of Heroes</h1>
    <h2>Sub Heading</h2>
    <hero-app-main [hero]=hero></hero-app-main>`,
  styles: ['h1 { font-weight: normal; font-size: 20px; }', 'h2 { font-size: 14px; }']
})
export class HeroAppComponent {
/* . . . */
}
```

Comment: I understand your point but my question is why we are passing it as an array unlike we do in case of template inline styles.

Comment: the question is why we use array

Answer (score 0):

For each component in angular you can write the styles in three ways but you can either use **stylesUrl** or **styles** only but not both.

***Example -1***: you can declare just a template with html and inline CSS.

```
      @Component({
      selector: 'app-course',
      template:`<p style="font-size:12px;color:red'> Welcome to the world of coding </p>`,
      })
```

***Example -2***: In this case styleUrls is used, where you give more than one .CSS
file name with its path.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-course',
       templateUrl: './course.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./course.component.css'],  
    })
```

***Example -3***: In this case you can directly write the CSS instead of maintaining
one separate .CSS file.

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-course',
       templateUrl: './course.component.html',
       styles: ['p { font-weight: normal; }']  
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to follow design structure pattern even  seems unnecessary required.

Answer (score -1):

For templates, you can only use one HTML template file per component. But for styles, it lets you add **multiple CSS files** for that particular component.

Comment: I agree we can bind multiple CSS files in styleUrls but in case with styles we are passing single style with multiple CSS properties then why are we sending it in array